# Coherence for order spectra

Tags: power-spectral-density, stft, coherence

The [scipy signal coherence](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.coherence.html) function computes for two time series the coherence as a function of the frequency. For rotating systems however, it is sometimes meaningful to analyze the two recorded signal measurements as [order spectra](https://www.head-acoustics.cn/downloads/eng/application_notes/OrderAnalysis_e.pdf). For an intuitive difference between lines of constant frequency and constant order, I use Figure 2 from [Order analysis in ArtemiS Suite - Head acoustics](https://www.head-acoustics.cn/downloads/eng/application_notes/OrderAnalysis_e.pdf).

[image: Constant frequency vs constant order]

What is the most suitable adaptation of the [scipy signal coherence](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.coherence.html) in order to get the coherence as a function of the order, instead of the frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic is to the best of my knowledge an area of open research. The research contribution which helped me most in solving my problem was: [The spectral analysis of cyclo-non-stationary signals](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S088832701500446X). Specifically, the key seems to be:

> "In this paper, it is shown that the optimal way of describing
> cyclo-non-stationary signals is jointly in the time and the angular
> domains."

[image: Angle-time cyclostationarity]